# I am trying to output in json where a key is equals to a particular value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

```
l = []
with open("acw_user_data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    headers = next(reader)
     
    for reader_row in reader:
       
        d = {}
        d[headers[11]] = str(reader_row[11])
        d[headers[13]] = str(reader_row[13])
        d[headers[3]] = int(reader_row[3])
        d[headers[18]] = str(reader_row[18])
        d[headers[16]] = bool(reader_row[16])

   import json
    with open("assignemt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(l, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
```

---

the result:

```
 {
            "First Name": "Jodie",
            "Last Name": "O'Brien",
            "Age (Years)": 57,
            "Sex": "Female",
            "Retired": true
            },
       {
            "First Name": "Leke",
            "Last Name": "Dan",
            "Age (Years)": 57,
            "Sex": "male",
            "Retired": false
            },
       {
            "First Name": "joe",
            "Last Name": "frank",
            "Age (Years)": 22,
            "Sex": "Female",
            "Retired": true
            }
```

I have this Json dump created from a csv file. But I want only the Json dump for only those where Age(Years) is equals to 22

I want to get the same result but only for those where age is 22 or where retired is true

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you leave out `l.append(d)`?

Comment: Based on your recent questions, I think you should learn Pandas, instead of writing all this conversion code yourself.

Comment: Yes i left out append.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I am trying to learn from basis. I already use pandas and i want to go back to this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

Age 22:

```
with open("assignemt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
    json.dump([d for d in l if d['Age (Years)'] == 22], jsonf)
```

Age 22 or retired:

```
with open("assignemt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
    json.dump([d for d in l if d['Age (Years)'] == 22 or d['Retired']], jsonf)
```